# Convert/move negative z-values in GTiff to positive

Tags: qgis, gdal, dem

I have a Float32 Gtiff which has the whole range in negative values. Is there a way to move or convert the values to positive values? Preferably with gdal or QGIS. The application I want to use doesn't support negative values.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a data standardization but you have to move the entire distribution to keep the negative values relative. You can do this using any software that allows for raster algebra (eg., QGIS, GRASS, ArcGIS, SAGA, etc...). This capacity is commonly found in a raster calculator (eg., QGIS menu "Raster > Raster Calculator"). The specific software syntax may vary slightly but follow common raster algebra logic.

The general syntax for standardizing a distribution, that deals with negative values, would be:

`( raster - minimum(raster) ) / ( maximum(raster) - minimum(raster) )`

This will standardize the values of the raster to a 0-1 range. If you do not have negative values you can just perform a simple row standardization by dividing the raster by the maximum value of the raster.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly both with qgis and gdal!